# Persist current data stored in isolated storage through a Windows Phone 7 Marketplace update?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7

In my experience, releasing a Windows Phone 7 app/game update will erase the isolated storage of the app.

If my user has already saved a lot of preferences (and I'm using isolated storage on the device to save this data), can I persist the data I've stored across an application update released through the Marketplace?

It's a bad user experience right now for them to download an app update and have all their preferences wiped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you storing the data you are expecting to persist?

The contents of IsolatedStorage should not normally be affected by installing an update but there are a few scenarios which may lead to your experience.

- If you're storing data in `IsolatedStorageSettings` but change the assembly which access these in the update. (The assembly name is used as part of the key to access this data so it will be looking in a different place after the update.)
- You are serializing/deserializing a model to the isostore and the updated version of the file in the new version can't deserialize the old version of the model. (You should specifically handle such situations.)
- You specifically deploy an empty file to isostore on first run, but don't check if a reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

> In my experience, releasing a windows phone 7 app/game update will erase the isolated storage of the app.

To bad, your "experience" is wrong. Updating a application *will not* erase the isolated storage for the app.

Comment: i'm glad to hear this! that means i just need to double check what i'm doing in the app across udpates. thanks for your reply